# Время доступ к элементам коллекций ?

Tags: java, коллекции

что-то в oracle-docs я не все нашел, поделитесь информацией ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо - вот нашел:

- [Java Collections QuickRef](http://lalitpant.blogspot.com/2007/07/java-collections-quickref.html)
- [Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html)
- [Java Collections JDK 6.0](http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf)